# Highchart panning series position change

Tags: highcharts, translate

[status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0aGk.png)

When you move the chart, the "oper"series at the bottom comes up
"oper" Yaxis is set to TOP: 90% and Height: 10%.
When moving the chart, the translate value is set to the initial value and moves.
Help anyone who knows how not to move the OPER series up when moving the chart.

```
Highcharts.chart( chartKind+'Chart', {
        chart: {
            panning: {
                enabled: true,
                type: 'xy'
            },
            zoomType: 'xy',
            pinchType :'xy',

        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            minTickInterval : 60 * 10000,
            width: "95%",
            offset: 10,
         
        },
        
         yAxis: [{
                height: '90%',
                labels : {
                    format: '{value:,.0f}'
                },
            },
            
            { 
                zoomEnabled: false,
                categories : ["OFF","ON"],
                top: '90%',
                height: '10%',
                title : { 
                    offset: -10,
                    align: 'high',
                    text : "Oper",
                },
                opposite: true
            },
        ],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you move the chart that yaxis title stays at the bottom, how can I reproduce this?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    panning: {
      enabled: true,
      type: 'xy'
    },
    zoomType: 'xy',
    pinchType: 'xy',
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    minTickInterval: 60 * 10000,
    width: "95%",
    offset: 10,

  },
  yAxis: [{
      height: '90%',
      labels: {
        format: '{value:,.0f}'
      },
    },
    {
      zoomEnabled: false,
      categories: ["OFF", "ON"],
      top: '90%',
      height: '10%',
      title: {
        offset: -10,
        align: 'high',
        text: "Oper",
      },
      opposite: true
    },
  ],
  series: [{
    data: [4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3],
    yAxis: 1,
  }, {
    data: [4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3].reverse()
  }]
});
```